# How do I delete element from arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Hello guys am working on an Android calculator app with a `textview` ,all text in the `textview` are entered into an `ArrayList`. So far every thing works fine except for the delete button, so if my  `ArrayList` contains elements `[12999,+,56,-,545]` what I have been trying to do is delete the last `String` of the `ArrayList`which is (5),so the `ArrayList`becomes `[12999,4,56,4,54]`. This is the code I have so far

```
public void delete(View view) {
    String s;
    into s1;
    s = maincalculator.getText.to      
    string();
    s1 = maincalculator.getText.to      
    string().length();
    if(s1 > 0)
    {
        s = s.substring(0, s1 - 1);
        maincalculator.setText(s);
        arraylist.set(arraylist.size, s);
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you go from  `[12999,+,56,-,545]` to `[12999,4,56,4,54]`.? There's missing information I'm not understanding. Why were `+` and `-` replaced by `4`? Wouldn't the last element be `-54`?

Comment: Sorry the question has been edited to and all error fixed

Answer (score 0):

You don't hold the result of deleted string. Use this.

```
String newStr = s.substring(0,s1-1);
maincalculator.setText(newStr);
arraylist.set(arraylist.size, newStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Whoa, first of all: name your variables to something meaningful, that makes the code easier to read and debug.

**Delete the last item from an ArrayList:**

```
myArrayList.remove(myArrayList.size() - 1)
```

`.size()` returns the item count, and `- 1` is to get the index (it starts at 0, right?).

Comment: Removing the last item tends to remove the whole content of the index e.g [3,44,55] removing the last index gives [3,44]. What I need is to remove part of the index to get [3,44,5] that is  removing 5

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Updated after I realized what you're trying to do. Try this:

```
    //Trim s to the substring that you want
    s = s.substring(0, s.length() - 1);
    //Set it to the last element in the arrayList
    arrayList.set(arrayList.size() - 1, s);
```